# BASH - if statement not working correctly

Tags: bash, alma-linux

I ran the script below once and it has appended `enforce_for_root` at the end of line when the match `pam_pwquality.so` has been found. However, for some reason it keeps entering the if `if ! grep -q "enforce_for_root" /etc/pam.d/system-auth` even though the entry already exists.

```
#!/bin/bash
source oem.properties

log_error() {
    echo "Error: $1" | /usr/bin/tee $ERROR_LOG
    echo "Aborting program ... "
    echo " "
    exit 10
}

echo " "
echo -n "Generating SSH keys ... "
if [ -f /home/rlee/.ssh/keys/$RSYNC_KEY ]; then
    echo "key exists, skipping."
else
    sudo -u rlee ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t $RSYNC_KEY_TYPE -f /home/rlee/.ssh/keys/$RSYNC_KEY -C "$RSYNC_KEY_COMMENT" -q -N ""
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then log_error "Generating SSH keys."; fi
    echo "OK"
fi
echo " "

echo "Add the public key to old OEM server."
echo "Create or modify the authorized_keys file on the old server."
echo "vim /home/rsync/.ssh/authorized_keys"
echo " "
echo "Add the following key: "
while true
do 
    cat /home/rlee/.ssh/keys/$RSYNC_KEY.pub
    echo " "
    read -p "Press 'C' to continue: " OPTION
    if [ $OPTION == 'C' ] || [ $OPTION == 'c' ]; then break; fi
done

echo -n "Testing SSH connection ... "
ssh -p $OLD_OEM_PORT -i /home/rlee/.ssh/keys/$RSYNC_KEY -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no rsync@$OLD_OEM_HOSTNAME exit
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then log_error "Testing SSH connection ... "; fi
echo "OK"

useradd llee
useradd nagios

# Enforce password policies
echo -n "Setting password policies ... "
authconfig --enablereqlower --enablerequpper --enablereqdigit --enablereqother --passminlen=12 --passmaxrepeat=3 --update
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then log_error "Setting password policies ... "; fi
echo "OK"

echo -n "Enforcing password policies on root ... "
if ! grep -q "enforce_for_root" /etc/pam.d/system-auth; then
    
    sed -i -e '/pam_pwquality.so/s/$/ enforce_for_root/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
    echo "doesn't exist"
fi
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then log_error "Enforcing password policies on root ... "; fi

exit
```

If I move this block of code anywhere before the `adduser` statement, it does not enter `if ! grep -q "enforce_for_root" /etc/pam.d/system-auth` which works as intended.

Why is this happening?

```
#!/bin/bash

log_error() {
    echo "Error: $1" | /usr/bin/tee $ERROR_LOG
    echo "Aborting program ... "
    echo " "
    exit 10
}


echo -n "Enforcing password policies on root ... "
if ! grep -q "enforce_for_root" /etc/pam.d/system-auth; then
    
    sed -i -e '/pam_pwquality.so/s/$/ enforce_for_root/' /etc/pam.d/system-auth
    echo "doesn't exist"
fi
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then log_error "Enforcing password policies on root ... "; fi
```

Comment: Your question centers around whether your `sed` command adds a string to a line in a file that your `grep -q` command will find when it's invoked on that file.  I suggest writing a very simple script that tests that sequence of actions: grep for the string, add the string with sed, grep again for the string.  It's likely the sed command doesn't add the string in a way that grep will see the string, but the large bulk of the rest of your script is concealing the issue.

Comment: You mention an `adduser` statement, but there is no such statement in the code.

Comment: ```adduser``` is actually after the statement, I've updated my post to reflect that. It turns out to be the ```authconfig``` that's causing the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The following line is causing the problem:
`authconfig --enablereqlower --enablerequpper --enablereqdigit --enablereqother --passminlen=12 --passmaxrepeat=3 --update`

Here's the message I get when running the `authconfig` command:

```
Running authconfig compatibility tool.
The purpose of this tool is to enable authentication against chosen services with authselect and minimum configuration. It does not provide all capabilities of authconfig.

IMPORTANT: authconfig is replaced by authselect, please update your scripts.
See man authselect-migration(7) to help you with migration to authselect
```

I have modified the `pwquality.conf` file instead

```
echo -n "Setting password policies ... "
sed -i -e '/# minlen =/s/# minlen/minlen/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e '/# ucredit =/s/# ucredit/ucredit/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e '/# lcredit =/s/# lcredit/lcredit/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e '/# dcredit =/s/# dcredit/dcredit/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e '/# ocredit =/s/# ocredit/ocredit/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e '/# enforcing =/s/# enforcing/enforcing/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e '/# enforce_for_root/s/# enforce_for_root/enforce_for_root/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e 's/minlen = .*/minlen = 12/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e 's/ucredit = .*/ucredit = 1/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e 's/lcredit = .*/lcredit = 1/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e 's/dcredit = .*/dcredit = 1/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
sed -i -e 's/ocredit = .*/ocredit = 1/' /etc/security/pwquality.conf
echo "OK"
```

Comment: And this solves the issue with the `grep` in the `if` statement, in what way?

Comment: For some reason when the ```authconfig``` command is run, it interferes with the BASH script. ```grep -q "enforce_for_root"``` works as intended: the exit code is 0 when a match is found and 1 when there is no match. From displaying the exit code,  we would expect the code to executed within the ```if``` statement when there is no match. However, this is not the case when the ```authconfig``` command is run. As an alternative to ```authconfig```, I have instead modified the ```/etc/security/pwquality.conf``` which achieves the same thing as if I were to run the ```authconfig``` command.

Comment: Is the script running with `set -e` or `set -o errexit` enabled?

Comment: ```set -e``` or ```set -o errexit``` has not been set.